# Trying to find the source of these three orbital elements

Tags: the-moon, ephemeris

I'm working through section 65 “Calculating the Moon's position” in *Practical Astronomy with your Calculator or Spreadsheet* (fourth edition) by Duffett-Smith and Zwart. They begin the calculations with the following stated orbital elements:

1. Moon's mean longitude at the epoch – 91.929336 degrees
2. mean longitude of the perigee at the epoch – 130.143076 degrees
3. mean longitude of the node at the epoch – 291.682547 degrees.

The epoch they are using is 2010 January 0.0, which as far as I can make out starts at the midnight between 30 and 31 December 2009.

My question is, where do they get these three orbital elements from? Looking through the JPL HORIZONS Web-Interface I can find no reference to anything resembling these elements for the epoch date in the ephemeris types ELEMENTS and OBSERVER. I admit I'm a complete novice with this sort of thing so I might have well missed the obvious. Thanks.

**MY EDIT - 7 Sept 2021**

I would have thought the Moon's mean longitude at the epoch would equal longitude of the ascending node + argument of perifocus + the Moon's mean anomaly (all at 2009-Dec-31 00:00:00.0000 TDB). According to the HORIZONS data this equals $$290.93+188.66+332.60=92.19,$$ which is pretty close to the given figure. I would also have thought that the Moon's mean longitude of the perigee at the epoch would equal longitude of the ascending node + argument of perifocus. According to the HORIZONS data this equals $$290.93+188.66=119.59,$$ which is not so close to the given figure. I have no idea how to find the mean longitude of the node at the epoch.